# Developer Console, github

Tags: github, salesforce, lightning

How do i check in code in Git Hub from Developer console.
I have been trying to browse, i saw we have to sync code to eclipse and then drop files to Git Hub.

Can anyone suggest me a standard way to do this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Salesforce Developer Console based out the UI cannot integrate with Git Hub to check in/out code.  You'll have to do it with files stored locally either using your IDE or terminal.  This is the same as working with any Git repo and really is unrelated to Salesforce.
There is a new feature called Salesforce DX that has a tighter integration with git repos, it's going beta in Summer 17.